# CSS Gadient Class Not Works in SelectList Dropdown Mozilla

Tags: css, css-selectors

This is my CSS Gadient Class which works fine in all browser except Mozilla and i used it for select list in html and for dropdown

```
.gradientButtonFro 
{
    `background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #f3f2f7), color-stop(1, #dddce0));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #f3f2f7 5%, #dddce0 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f3f2f7 5%, #dddce0 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #f3f2f7 5%, #dddce0 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #f3f2f7 5%, #dddce0 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #f3f2f7 5%, #dddce0 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f3f2f7', endColorstr='#dddce0',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#f3f2f7;
    -moz-border-radius:11px;
    -webkit-border-radius:11px;
    border-radius:11px;
    border:1px solid #6a779e;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:black;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:17px;
//  padding:18px 42px;
    text-decoration:none;
}`
```

Comment: <select class="gradientButtonFro " style="height:42px;width:100px;font-size:1.8rem;>
  /* options  */                                                       
</select>   .... this the html section for the above css

Comment: please provide a working example